# Is there a way to force a context switch without Task.Delay in async code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have code with looks something like:

I was trying to avoid putting it in a Task.Run because it is async and should run fine on the main thread

However it does not do a context switch (and will run forever), unless I insert a Task.Delay into the loop

Is there a better way of achieving this (Without Task.Run)?

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
tasks.Add(DoSomething(cts.Token));
cts.Cancel();
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
Console.WriteLine("Done");

async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        await Task.Delay(1); // Without this is doesn't do context switch
    }
}
```

I'm trying to unit test cancellation when I have a heavy workload an encountered this problem.

Comment: What's a problem with using `Task.Delay`?

Comment: try Task.Yield?

Comment: Task.Yield is perfect! Thanks I didn't know about it. You can post as answer if you want I will accept it

Comment: `async..await` in itself does not force code to run asynchronously. It only makes it possible to do so in an elegant and transparant way.
So an async method will always run synchronously up to the point where you force a context switch (e.g. by using `await Task.Run(...)`, `await Task.Yield` or awaiting another async method that has asynchronous code).

Comment: @RedRidingHood added an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```cs
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //await Task.CompletedTask; //you can omit this line
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simulate a cancelable operation, the simplest way is probably this:

```
Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken);
}
```

The `cancellationToken` parameter has [canceling semantics](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/), meaning that when the token is canceled, the `Task` will transition to the [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) state. If you want it to have stopping semantics, which is the non standard semantics for a `CancellationToken`, you could do this:

```
async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    try { await Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, stoppingToken); }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
}
```

Now when the token is canceled, the `Task` will transition to the `RanToCompletion` state. Be aware that it's extremely rare to see a `CancellationToken` parameter with stopping semantics in the standard .NET libraries.